# Running OpenGL Apps on Android x86 4.4 R1 in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, android, hyper-v, opengl

I want to use Android x86 on a virtual machine on Windows 8.1 Pro, but I have Problems with 
OpenGl. I use the news Android Version (x86 4.4-r1) but I had also tried RC2.
Android x86 is always running. I can use the play store and surf in the internet, but when I use Apps which need OpenGL, it doesn’t work.
I see in the log file: unimplemented OpenGL ES API.
I used Virtual Box, VM Workstation and Hyper V but I always have the same problem. (In Virtual Box and VM Workstation I activated the 3D graphic options.)

I thought Android x86 now supports OpenGL with Intel graphic devices or do I have to change some options?

Host system:
Mainboard Asus H87m-Pro;
Intel i7-4790 (with GPU Intel HD 4600);
No other GPU installed;
16 GB Ram;
Windows 8.1 Pro;
Every Windows Update and latest driver installed.

Guest system
Android x86;
RAM 4, 1 GB;
HDD 12 GB;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android x86 doesn't have any OpenGL emulation. (Related:[Running OpenGL App on Android x86 and VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/725713/running-opengl-app-on-android-x86-and-virtualbox))

The possible alternatives are:

- [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)
- The default Android emulator bundled with SDK